# Deno: How to use WebSocket with oak?

Tags: websocket, deno

As Deno was released last Wednesday, I tried to play with it and redo the little example Chat App, I tried this:

```
import { Application, Router, send } from 'https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts';
import { listenAndServe } from 'https://deno.land/std/http/server.ts'

const app = new Application();
const router = new Router();

router
  .get('/ws', handleSocket);


app.use(router.routes());
app.use(router.allowedMethods());

await app.listen({ port: HTTP_PORT });
```

app.ts

```
import { WebSocket, acceptWebSocket, isWebSocketCloseEvent, acceptable } from 'https://deno.land/std/ws/mod.ts'
import { v4 } from 'https://deno.land/std/uuid/mod.ts'

const users = new Map<string, WebSocket>()

export const handleSocket = async (ctx: any) => {
  if (acceptable(ctx.request.serverRequest)) {
    const { conn, r: bufReader, w: bufWriter, headers } = ctx.request.serverRequest;
    const socket = await acceptWebSocket({
      conn,
      bufReader,
      bufWriter,
      headers,
    });

    await socketEventHandlers(socket);
  } else {
    throw new Error('Error when connecting websocket');
  }
}
...

export const socketEventHandlers = async (ws: WebSocket): Promise<void> => {
  // Register user connection
  const userId = v4.generate()

  users.set(userId, ws)
  await broadcast(`> User with the id ${userId} is connected`)

  // Wait for new messages
  for await (const event of ws) {
    const message = typeof event === 'string' ? event : ''

    await broadcast(message, userId)

    // Unregister user conection
    if (!message && isWebSocketCloseEvent(event)) {
      users.delete(userId)
      await broadcast(`> User with the id ${userId} is disconnected`)
    }
  }
}
```

socket.ts

The websocket connection works perfectly with the `import { listenAndServe } from 'https://deno.land/std/http/server.ts'`
, but with the code above I got errors like `WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/ws' failed: Invalid frame header`.

Does anybody have any tips to solve it? Thx ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue happens because you're using the wrong version of the libraries. Always use versioned URLs in Deno.

For Deno `1.0.0`, you'll need to use [`oak v4.0.0`](https://github.com/oakserver/oak/releases) & `std v0.51.0`

**app.ts**

```
import { Application, Router, send } from 'https://deno.land/x/oak@v4.0.0/mod.ts';
```

**socket.ts**

```
import { WebSocket, acceptWebSocket, isWebSocketCloseEvent, acceptable } from 'https://deno.land/std@0.51.0/ws/mod.ts'
import { v4 } from 'https://deno.land/std@0.51.0/uuid/mod.ts'
```

Once you make those changes, you'll be able to connect correctly to the WebSocket Server.

```
const ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8080/ws")
ws.onopen = function () {
  ws.send('OAK is working!')
}
```

Answer (score 5):

TL;DR - This has been updated since answer was accepted and is much simpler now.

```
router.get('/ws', async ctx => {
    const sock = await ctx.upgrade();
    handleSocket(sock);
});
```

Credit https://github.com/oakserver/oak/pull/137

Comment: https://github.com/oakserver/oak/issues/214
https://deno.land/manual/runtime/http_server_apis#websocket-support
https://deno.land/manual/runtime/http_server_apis_low_level#serving-websockets
(in the above answer https://github.com/oakserver/oak/pull/137)